# game center problem on 3g?

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator, cocos2d-iphone

i have developed a game in cocos2d and implement game-center in it its working well on simulator

but when i am trying to install it on my 3g error comes device not supported by game ...

i know 3g does not support game center ... so can it be happen my game install on 3g

no problem game-center not work but it can install on 3g .. actually i am avoiding to

develop two versions of game one for game center devices and one for not game center supported devices..

waiting for help..

Regards

Haseeb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should weak link your framework.. go to your framework and weaklink GameKit.framework..

Answer (score 0):

You should read the section in the GameKit Development Guide about "Optionally Supporting Game Center in your App"

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html